Building Tx with cardano-api
Can anybody provide an example of building a simple Tx using just Haskell and Cardano-Api?
(I know that there are other great tools for building Tx's, but I'm curious about using Cardano-Api.)

Cardano faucet uses API directly to build it's transactions:
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-faucet/blob/f1b83b4fe649c6dabffa483820f0d5ec47fb2633/cardano-faucet/src/Cardano/Faucet/TxUtils.hs#L25

Great example, thanks!

Sam's example is perfectly fine however we have another way to construct txs that may be more convenient via various lenses:
https://github.com/IntersectMBO/cardano-cli/blob/25a9cfd09052ce838dd08f6da3a22c24bc474a9d/cardano-cli/src/Cardano/CLI/EraBased/Run/Transaction.hs#L871
Then you can call makeTransactionBodyAutoBalance to create a balanced tx.

Great!  Thanks for the reference.
